# Azure Search - Search by multi word string and then individual words

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am very new to Azure Search services and I have a requirement that the user can send in a search string "my search string". The Search should bring back all corresponding entries that contain the searchString and then it should also break the searchString into individual words and bring back entries that contain the word or words

It then needs to rank the results based on entries containing the entire string and then followed by entries that contain the word(s)

Not sure how to go about this in Azure Search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure lucence search function search=*&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$filter=search.ismatch('/*.search term.*/', 'fieldname', 'simple', 'all').It will work

Comment: I had to make one minor adjustment: search=&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$filter=search.ismatch('/.search term.*/', 'fieldname', 'simple', 'any')

And then it brought back rows that contained the string and rows that contained any of the individual rows.

One other question, how do I order the results so the results that contained the entire string come back first?

Comment: There is not a way to sort in this way directly from Azure Search that I am aware of.  I think for this you might want to send this as two queries where you get the entire string results first and sort those and then get the others.  Although in this case you would need to remove duplicates from the second query and you would lose your ability to do paging.   One thing I would check before you do this is whether you really need to do this as I wonder if the ones with the entire string already come back higher based on the scoring.